# Database project in VS 2010 can't build/verify script with sys.syscolumns

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to build a database project with just newly created script containing references to sys.syscolumns and sys.sysobjects.

The error says

```
Error   12  SQL03006: 
View: [dbo].[UtilityTableColumnView] has an unresolved reference to 
    object [sys].[syscolumns].  ...\Schemas\dbo\Views\UtilityTableColumnView.view.sql
```

VS 2010 is running under Administrator account who is admin on local SQL server 2008 Developer edition.

The script is

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[UtilityTableColumnView] AS 

    SELECT 
        O.[id] AS TableSystemId, 
        O.[name] AS TableName, 
        C.[id] AS ColumnSystemId, 
        C.[name] AS ColumnName, 
        C.xtype AS ColumnSystemXType, 
        C.typestat AS ColumnSystemTypeStat, 
        C.xusertype AS ColumnSystemXUserType, 
        C.[length] AS ColumnSystemLength, 
        C.xprec AS ColumnSystemXPrec, 
        C.colid AS SystemColId, 
        C.colorder AS SystemColumnOrder 
    FROM 
        sys.syscolumns C INNER JOIN 
        sys.sysobjects O ON O.[id] = C.[id] 
    WHERE 
        O.xtype = 'U'
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the system database catalog to your project. Add a reference to the schema file located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Extensions\SqlServer\2008\DBSchemas to your db project references.

Comment: For anyone that comes up with this answer doing a Google search these files have moved in more recent versions of Visual Studio.  You should look in C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio XX.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer You then have folders for each version of SQL server, that will contain the dacpac files for master and msdb.

Comment: Also, we're talking about "Add Database Reference" to select the appropriate dacpac